# User signup and log in (Firebase Cloudstore iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, server, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase's realtime database, there are a lot of examples for doing user authentication (sign up and log in). Can anyone help me out with implementing this in their new Firestore database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase **Auth service is independent** from real time database or cloudstore, whether you are using one or the other, the auth implementation is the same:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine

Another topic would be if you want to store users additionally in the DB and match them with the auth user, which would be a pure **how-to-cloudstore** topic:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/how-to